# Create Gallery Like layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to develop an app like this. Which is exactly like android gallery.
So I tried with `HorizontalScrollView`. But still I am facing some problems

[image]

Here is my layout.

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/hScrollView"/>

<HorizontalScrollView
android:id="@+id/hScrollView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    
    </LinearLayout>
    
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

and here is my code

```
LinearLayout image;
ImageView main;

ImageView[] iv=new ImageView[images.length];
int i;
```

and in Activity,

```
for(i=0;i<images.length;i++)
    {
        iv[i]=new ImageView(this);
        
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        iv[i].setLayoutParams(lparams);
        iv[i].setImageResource(images[i]);
        
        iv[i].setTag(images[i]);
        
        image.addView(iv[i]);
        
        iv[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                main.setImageResource((Integer) iv[i].getTag());    
            }
        });
```

But it is always giving me `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`. I know Value of `i` is getting updated for each iteration.
So What am I supposed to do? Any alternative ways are appreciable.

**I am using api level 18 so `Gallery`  won't work.**

Comment: What, you don't know how to use the WYSIWYG GUI?

Comment: @user2310289: I am new to android so I don't know.

Comment: What tool are you using?  Did you try?  If you drag and drop stuff, it even works.

Comment: @user2310289: I am using eclipse. I am going through WYSIWYG GUI. Didn't tried yet..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/hScrollView"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/hScrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In Activity class:

```
int[] drawable = { R.drawable.background, R.drawable.forground,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    centerImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    for (int i = 0; i < drawable.length; i++) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ImageView view = new ImageView(this);
        view.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        view.setId(i);
        view.setImageResource(drawable[i]);
        linearLayout.addView(view);

        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                        centerImageView.setImageResource(drawable[v.getId()]);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Hope will help you:)

Comment: thnx for your answer... But when I use `view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()` for clicking event of any image (`view`) , it is displaying me only last image for big image. I want to display the clickd image, so can you help me out on this??

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

     <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/examplegallery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**JAVA**

```
 private Integer[] Imgid = {

        R.drawable.a_1, R.drawable.a_2, R.drawable.a_3, R.drawable.a_4, R.drawable.a_5, R.drawable.a_6, R.drawable.a_7

};

 ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
imgView.setImageResource(Imgid[0]);

Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.examplegallery);
gallery.setAdapter(new AddImgAdp(this));

gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
imgView.setImageResource(Imgid[position]);
}
});
```

**Reference :**

http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2010/05/gallery-view-android-developer-tutorial.html

http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-gallery-view-example.html

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-gallery-imageview-example

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/

Comment: Thnx for your help. But as I clearly mentioned, I can't use gallery as galary is deprecated now.. So can you suggest me another way??

Comment: @Rohit You can either go for `HorizontalScrollView` or `GridView`.

Comment: @GrIsHu: I am trying to use `HorizontalScrollView` and `ViewPager`.

Answer (score 1):

**Please note:** [android.widget.Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) is no longer supported. Other horizontally scrolling widgets include `HorizontalScrollView` and `ViewPager` from the support library.

As per your requirement the `HorizontalScrollView` is more suitable. Check out the below tutorial which will help you in implementation.

[Implement HorizontalScrollView like GalleryView](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/07/implement-gallery-like.html)